# Huge AboutIconData block in add-in file

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, extensibility

In my generated .addin files for visual studio, I get really huge chunks of binary data under the `AboutIconData` property. Can anyone suggest as to why this data keeps on growing with time, and whether I can safely remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Its only the icon encoded in Base64, I never seen that data get bigger over time. (but on the other hand The file I hardly ever modified and its read only by the source control)